# Batch set /a and copy

Tags: batch-file

Problem here is that the part where the program counts the amount of files to copy and copies them isn't working. In my tests the %levelcount%  was 4, at some point it copied only the file level_4.lvl.

here is config.ini:

```
mapname=maze
mode=123
metadata=a brief description
sound=
config=
levelcount=4
```

batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

::Thanks to reddit.com/u/Danoodle

:: The source file to parse.
set "infile=%~1"
if not defined infile set /p "infile=Source file>"
:: Default output filename. Set blank to discard anything prior to the first #.
set "outfile="
:: Extension to use for output files. Set blank if the extension is given by the # line.
set "outext=%~x1"

:: Here begins the program.
rem %%@ is the line number (1,2,...); %%A is the line contents.
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%@ in ('findstr /n "^^" "!infile!"') do (
    set "line=%%A"
    if "!line:~0,1!" == "#" (
        set "outfile=!line:~1!!outext!"
    ) else if defined outfile (
        1>> "!outfile!" echo/!line!
    )
)
endlocal
if exist "animation.txt" copy /a "animation.txt" "animation" & del animation.txt
if exist "config.txt" copy /a "config.txt" "config.ini" & del config.txt
if exist "autorun.txt" copy /a "autorun.txt" "autorun.bat" & del autorun.txt

mkdir levels
for /f  "delims=" %%A in (config.ini) do set "%%A"


:copylevel
copy "level_%levelcount%.txt" "levels\level_%levelcount%.lvl 
del /q "level_%levelcount%.txt"
if "%levelcount%==1" goto end
set /a "levelcount=%levelcount%-1"
goto copylevel


:end
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think replace from `:copylevel` to the end with the following:

```
for /L %%I in (%levelcount%,-1,1) do (
    if exist "level_%%I.txt" (
        >NUL move /y "level_%%I.txt" "levels\level_%%I.lvl"
    )
)
```

A `for /L` loop should be faster than a `goto` loop anyway, and you won't have to worry about decrementing `%levelcount%` via `set /a`.

As for what was causing the above script to break, I think it's the `if "%levelcount%==1" goto end` line.  You have to quote each parameter individually, not both together.  It should've been `if "%levelcount%"=="1"` or `if %levelcount% equ 1`.

Comment: Along with what rojo said, remove the spaces around the `==` in this if statement `if "!line:~0,1!" == "#" (`  batch if statements are completely literal in comparisons `if "!line:~0,1!"=="#" (`